# Refreshing a button in Android

Tags: java, android

I have set a content view in Android with:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Now after one of the buttons is clicked, the following code is executed to enable another button:

```
ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                buttonPause.setEnabled(true);
...
```

This enables the button. BUT only after a minute or so.

Do I need to refresh the button or layout? Or is that bad practice? I am wondering what causes this delay. I have read about notifyDataSetChanged(), but I do not think that is the right method.

Comment: should not take a minute unless something is blocking the ui thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`notifyDataSetChanged()` has nothing to do with `Buttons`, but with `Adapters`.

Did you try to add a `buttonPause.invalidate()` right after enabling it ?

Comment: You should post the whole code from the onClick() method because there is probably something that take a long time and prevent the UI thread from leaving the onClick() method and refreshing the button's state.

Comment: Yes, you are probably right. Let me try using runnable to execute things in different threads. I will keep you posted.